# Is there a python function to shift revenue column by specific timedelta?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-wrangling

Please refer to the image attached

I have a data frame that has yearly revenue in columns (2020 to 2025). I want to shift the revenue in those columns by a given time delta(column Time Shift). The time delta I have is in terms of days. Is there an efficient way to make the shift?

E.G

[image: Masked example of the data I have]

What I want to achieve is to shift the yearly revenue in columns by the value of days in the Time Shift column i.e. 4 days of revenue to shift from column to column ( i.e. 1.27[116/365 * 4] should be shifted from 2022 to 2023 for the 1st row)

Thanks in Advance

Text Input data

```
Launch Date Launch Date Base    Time Shift  2020    2021    2022   2023   2024    2025
2022-06-01  2022-06-01          4   0   0   115.98  122.93  119.22  35.31
2025-02-01  2025-02-01          4   0   0   0           0           0           66.18859318
2022-09-01  2022-09-01          4   49.42   254.86  191.12          248.80          206.53          98.22
2025-01-01  2025-01-01          4   0   0   0           0           14.47           54.24
2022-06-01  2022-06-01          4   0   0   50.25       53.26       51.65       15.30
2025-02-01  2025-02-01          4   0   0   0       0       0       28.67
2022-09-01  2022-09-01          4   148.20  758.22  535.45      676.73      545.42      251.83
2025-01-01  2025-01-01          4   0   0   0       0       38.23       139.07
2022-06-01  2022-06-01          4   0   0   140.78      144.88      136.41      39.23
```

Comment: please add a sample input & out dataframe as text

Comment: @Manakin I have added the data as text, let me know if this works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can figour out how much to shift per year and then subtract from the current year and add to the next year.

Get the column names of interest

```
ycols = [str(n) for n in range(2020,2026)]
```

calculate the amount that needs shifting, per year (to the next year):

```
shift_df = df[ycols].multiply(df['Time_Shift']/365.0, axis=0)
```

looks like this

```
        2020     2021      2022      2023      2024      2025
--  --------  -------  --------  --------  --------  --------
 0  0         0        1.27101   1.34718   1.30652   0.386959
 1  0         0        0         0         0         0.725354
 2  0.541589  2.79299  2.09447   2.72658   2.26334   1.07638
 3  0         0        0         0         0.158575  0.594411
 4  0         0        0.550685  0.583671  0.566027  0.167671
 5  0         0        0         0         0         0.314192
 6  1.62411   8.30926  5.86795   7.41622   5.97721   2.75978
 7  0         0        0         0         0.418959  1.52405
 8  0         0        1.54279   1.58773   1.4949    0.429918
```

Now create a copy of df (could use the original if you want of course) and apply the operations:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2[ycols] = df2[ycols] - shift_df[ycols]
df2[ycols[1:]] =df2[ycols[1:]] + shift_df[ycols[:-1]].values
```

slightly tricky bits here are in the last line -- we use the indexing `[1:]` and `[:-1]` appropriately to access previous year shift, and also use `.values` method otherwise the column labels do not match and you can do do the addition.

After this we get df2:

```
    Launch_Date    Launch_Date_Base      Time_Shift      2020     2021      2022     2023      2024      2025
--  -------------  ------------------  ------------  --------  -------  --------  -------  --------  --------
 0  2022-06-01     2022-06-01                     4    0         0      114.709   122.854  119.261    36.2296
 1  2025-02-01     2025-02-01                     4    0         0        0         0        0        65.4632
 2  2022-09-01     2022-09-01                     4   48.8784  252.609  191.819   248.168  206.993    99.407
 3  2025-01-01     2025-01-01                     4    0         0        0         0       14.3114   53.8042
 4  2022-06-01     2022-06-01                     4    0         0       49.6993   53.227   51.6676   15.6984
 5  2025-02-01     2025-02-01                     4    0         0        0         0        0        28.3558
 6  2022-09-01     2022-09-01                     4  146.576   751.535  537.891   675.182  546.859   255.047
 7  2025-01-01     2025-01-01                     4    0         0        0         0       37.811   137.965
 8  2022-06-01     2022-06-01                     4    0         0      139.237   144.835  136.503    40.295
```

As you noticed the amount shifted from year 2026 is 'lost' ie we do not assign it to any new column

Comment: Hey, @piterbarg , just a quick query. This works when we shift direction is forward. But what if the Timeshift column had both +ve and -ve values. That means in some case we need to shift the rev forward and in a few other cases we need to shift it backward

Comment: this would not quite work then. I would split the df into sub-dfs with positive and negative shifts and pply slightly different logic to each part. By splitting I mean to use boolean indexing on the positive and negative shifts.  eg `pos = df['Time_Shift'] > 0 df2.loc[pos,ycols[1:]] =df2.loc[pos,ycols[1:]] + shift_df.loc[pos,ycols[:-1]].values` and slightly different but very similar logic for `df2.loc[~pos,ycols[:-1]] = ...`

Comment: `df2.loc[~pos,ycols[:-1]] = df2.loc[~pos,ycols[:-1]] + shift_df.loc[~pos,ycols[1:]].values` this will be the logic for the left shift when the delta in -ve right

Comment: indeed. But also I think you want to modify the shift_df calc to add `abs` somthing like this `shift_df = df[ycols].multiply(abs(df['Time_Shift'])/365.0, axis=0)`